# How can I apply CSS stylesheets to a specific component?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, next.js

I'm working on Android app & web app in the same Next.js project and I want the recommended [Ionic global stylesheets](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/global-stylesheets) to not apply on web layout.

I have a client component imported in server component `app/layout.tsx` that looks like this:

```
<>
  <WindowContextProvider>
    {Capacitor.isNativePlatform() ? (
     <NoSSRWrapper>
      <NativeLayout>{children}</NativeLayout>
     </NoSSRWrapper>
    ) : (
     <WebLayout>{children}</WebLayout>
    )}
  </WindowContextProvider>
</>
```

In the `NativeLayout` is where I've imported all the Ionic global stylesheets but they still apply on the `WebLayout`, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS using style tag inside the same specific component, Otherwise, you can apply CSS by targeting it with a specific class name.
[image]

Comment: I get that but the main problem is that some of the Ionic styles don't have a specific classname but rather styled html tags: a: {color: blue} etc.. so this also effects all the other html tags in another layout. But now when I think about it isn't much of a big deal since whatever html tag I use, I will style them anyways and it will override the default styles set by Ionic stylesheets. But still I would like to know how to apply CSS to a specific component.